# Infinite dimensional lattice for integers and the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, discrete-geometry, lattice-polytopes

It is known that for each finite set of primes $p$ we have: $\log(p)$ are linear independent over the rational numbers.

We have $\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)$ and $\log(n) = \sum_{p |n}v_p(n) \log(p)$.

We define $\psi(n) := \sum_{p |n}v_p(n) e_p$ where $e_p$ is the $p$-th standard basis vector of the Hilbert space of sequences.

for $q = a/b \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ we define:

$$\psi(a/b) := \psi(a/\gcd(a,b))-\psi(b/\gcd(a,b))$$.

We have for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$|\psi(n)|^2 = \sum_{p|n} v_p(n)^2 \text{ is a natural number}$$

Furthermore the function

$$K(a,b) = \left < \psi(a),\psi(b)\right >  = \sum_{p|\gcd(a,b)} v_p(a)v_p(b)$$

is a positive definite kernel on the natural numbers.

Let us define the $\infty$-dimensional lattice $\Gamma$ as:

$\Gamma:= {\psi(q)| q \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}, |\psi(q)|^2 \equiv 0 \mod(2)}$$

and let us also define:

$$\eta(n) := (-1)^{|\psi(n)|^2}= \prod_{p|n}(-1)^{v_p(n)^2}$$

For $\psi(a),\psi(b) \in \Gamma$ we have:

$$|\psi(ab)|^2 = |\psi(a)+\psi(b)|^2 = |\psi(a)|^2+|\psi(b)|^2+2K(a,b) \equiv 0+0+0 \equiv 0 \mod(2)$$

Therefore $\psi(a)+\psi(b) \in \Gamma$ and $\psi(1) \in \Gamma$.

The lattice shares some properties with the Leech-lattice and the E8 lattice:

1. It is unimodular in the sense that: For a finite set of primes, the gram matrix $(K(p,q))_{p,q \text{ is prime}}$ has $\det=1$.
2. It is even: $\forall x \in \Gamma: |x|^2 \equiv 0 \mod(2)$
3. For all nonzero vectors in the lattice the squared norm is at least $2$.

My questions are these:

```
1) Probably an easy question:
```

$$\eta(mn) = \eta(m) \eta(n) \forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}$$

```
2) Does it satisfy a Riemann-Hypothesis type of random variable equality:
```

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 : \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N^{1/2+\epsilon}}\sum_{n=1}^N \eta(n) = 0$$

```
3) Is there a relationship to the Riemann Hypothesis and this lattice?
```

[Here is some Sagemath code for experiments.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFUsFugzAMvSPxD5F6cQKjMGmXSvxCLz2iagoldGlpyBLK9vlzAhS6rVuk0tjYz-89U4maiI6DopswIHiM6K5GEXu9QM-bK-9kq0DFmjJN6tYQTaQi2siLeK1kL21rLDbTMAiDCrHOZ-Bx-ScYd2BzWGL4EPl4qDzePODCOzDm2wBMGvkJRTGO93jc4Rmz90E5Bh5nQOrFAYVt8yxNJ7jVjuRkt0NBQ2wxxLKuNbBlRbof0499GHHc6V3vnYPzOxvdcIueyJqcSJ4jpGisIKnHP3nCXB0FZPE2yug0fPJ0klHXP5YHTxll7JcVsuf_dhgG3pDU3YxBCY20aPjII0uRCNYt7N3MlpR3Ge_nfMVxqnPLiZEwpwyfJc1zFzDcL1mcRf_c5bbFcVtbGrlr6a957tNsiBYGD1K0RgHFPgyswgtqEtrif5INCtTSYid6shHLcUHe2CEx0PCJ2E7J1eyP93L0cMHbmHj8XBMccwZ6CyvRwVSsdcK1FqoCXJJVa8UYpMlLhGTpDLgs4qUFpLG276aDZ6ZY0x7B_ZDArSUMGqkEaE0T-9Z-AP0CcX8RcQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

And here is some picture concerning the 2. question:

[image: infinite_dimensional_lattice_riemann_hypothesis]

**Edit**:
Let $\lambda(n)=(-1)^{\Omega(n)}$ be the Liouville funciton.

Then because $v_p(n)^2\equiv v_p(n) \mod(2)$, we have indeed:

$$\eta(n)= \lambda(n)$$

This answers the first question since it is known that $\lambda$ is multiplicative.

This also answers the second and third question.

Modified question: Is this lattice known in literature?

Thans for your help.

Comment: Viewing numbers $n = \prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ as being part of a lattice $\log n = \sum_i e_i \log p_i$ is a perspective one can take on developing factoring algorithms, see for example [this](https://pkc.iacr.org/2021/files/ducas.pdf).

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: What does it mean for one real number (log(p)) to be "independent as a vector over the rational numbers" when p is prime?

Comment: @DanielAsimov: I meant it in the way described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134770/prove-linear-combinations-of-logarithms-of-primes-over-mathbbq-is-independe

Comment: In the "picture concerning the 2. question", what do the axes represent?

Comment: At some point the question appears to switch from looking at factorizations of positive integers to factorizations of positive rational numbers. But then rational numbers are never mentioned again. Is that intentional?

Comment: @DanielAsimov: The picture 2. shows the points $(n,y_n)$ connected by a line between two points, where $y_n := \frac{1}{n^{1/2+\epsilon}}\sum_{k=1}^n \eta(k)$.

Comment: @DanielAsimov: The positive rational numbers correspond to points on the lattice $\Gamma$ with negative coefficients. You are right, that one does not need to have negative coefficients if one is interested only in counting primes. This leads to polytopes with non-negative coefficients corresponding to natural numbers with Ehrhart polynomials. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

A maybe useful point of view, is to use the Ehrhart polynomial of a polytope, namely the simplex, to count the numbers as points in a simplex:

Let $Q_N:=$ Polytope of $(\{\psi(p)|1\le p \le N, p \text{ prime }\})$

Then the polytope generated by the primes is the simplex, and it is known ( "Computing the continuous discretely" Matthias Beck, Sinai Robins, Second edtion, p.31 ff) that the Ehrhart polynomial is given by:

$$L(Q_N,t) = \operatorname{binomial}(d+t,d)$$

where $d= \pi(N)$ is the dimension of the simplex, and it is equal to the number of primes $\le N$, which is denoted by $\pi(N)$. Let $\hat{\pi}(n):=\{p \text{ prime}: p|n \}$ and let $p_n:=n$-th prime.

Since $L(Q_N,t)$ counts the points $\psi(n)=(x_1,\cdots,x_d)$ in the dilated polytope $t Q_N$ and those points have cooridnates $\ge 0$ with  $x_1+\cdots+x_d \le t$, we conclude that, by observing that the sum of the coordinates correspond to $\Omega(n) := \sum_{p|n} v_p(n)$:

$$L(Q_N,t) = |\{\psi(n) : \Omega(n) \le t , \hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!), 1 \le n \le p_{\pi(N)}^t\}|$$

The condition $\hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!)$ is for making sure we look at those numbers which have only prime divisors $\le N$.

We also observe that:

$$L(Q_N,t)-L(Q_N,t-1) = |\{ n : 1 \le n \le p_d^t, \Omega(n)=t, \hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!) \}| = |A_{N,t}|$$

where I have defined:

$$A_{N,t} = \{ n : 1 \le n \le p_d^t, \Omega(n)=t, \hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!) \}$$

We can now define and try to evalute the following sum:

$$F(N,t):= \sum_{k=0}^t \sum_{n \in A_{N,k}} \lambda(n)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^t (-1)^k ( L(Q_N,k)-L(Q_N,k-1) )$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^t (-1)^k ( \operatorname{binomial}(d+k,d)-\operatorname{binomial}(d+k-1,d) )$$

which according to Wolfram Alpha is equal to:

$$=((-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(d+t+1,d) F_{2,1}(1,d+t+2;t+2;-1)+2^{-d-1})-2^{-d-1}(2^{d+1}(-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(d+t,d)F_{2,1}(1,d+t+1;t+1;-1))$$
$$=((-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(\pi(N)+t+1,\pi(N)) F_{2,1}(1,\pi(N)+t+2;t+2;-1)+2^{-\pi(N)-1})-2^{-\pi(N)-1}(2^{\pi(N)+1}(-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(\pi(N)+t,\pi(N))F_{2,1}(1,\pi(N)+t+1;t+1;-1))$$

where $F_{2,1}(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function.

I must admit that the formula is not really "nice" but I think it should be useful, because using the RHS of the last equality with $d$ could maybe be extended to other values for $d,t$ other than the natural numbers.

I can also not see, how to relate the sum $F(N,t)$ to the Liouville sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \lambda(n)$$

The naive idea is that in the limit $N\rightarrow \infty, t \rightarrow \infty$, the two sets:

$$\mathbb{N}:= \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\{1,\cdots,N\} \text{ and } \lim_{N,t\rightarrow \infty} A_{N,t} $$

should be intuitively equal.

There is also an equivalent formulation of the Riemann Hypothesis with the points on a different polytope, but while it uses the Ehrhardt polynomials, which in this case are very complicated at $t=1$ I can not see how to derive an analytic formula in this case.

Here you can find some sanity check in [SageMaths](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJy9VNtq4zAQfQ_kHwR9GTm-1CFPhbwvdMl-QCjFjWRbOJaNNC7N369Gjh21YVkXljUhaHzmcmbmyEKW7FcrqwI0f1qvmHuMxMFoZocW3ovzUKDqNOi456zsDOuZ0qw3qpWvQr0r2xnrQvl6tV4Jl-tc22c4xBg3UzrB9lf_XsGB39WAJOdRNHHwNTTVMIWuJOSxxvrVx4NwfrjJOVMlsxLhnkWqrB3eCJtxCwcXwjkrtJg73e-bkPFPZdGRXkT5qP9GsflXFF-I4kjS1PaRxrqEIWDiaLwp3bWqOINIMMljwTMQrsqGUJo4hA4O3hA6-gRFn5eO5brGJsy7aVzeJLQ9kVEsDzVib5-yTHSn1BaVbAus085UWY3tOZM6M7KURuqTzMpBn0iFNiPHwKwvvTSV7FqJRp1SipzIU1n4iC9fVF0VbVvAh-91PF_cObq-Tsjgn8b-Y_HYxwmgn7xr1inVNRt9pghH99JB25f46P9dzGYbReCXQr_ZiICOtI_oa-Y_58193tznTfKgE6fypY3cLuV1m-Emb1v016AJr4HSCMhpgmxM-PD_r3ko3u80PGv9vi2cNEEh6xXhhxu-i7e7x6kKYRjG5rsJoscR0Oi_jrOwUg08npZDBv8NrXud7Q==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

```
def Omega(n):
    return sum(valuation(n,p) for p in prime_divisors(n))

def lhsK(N,t,k):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return sum((-1)**Omega(n) for n in range(1,nth_prime(d)**t+1) if set(prime_divisors(n)).issubset(set(primes(N+1))) and Omega(n)==k)

def lhsList(N,k):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return [n for n in range(1,nth_prime(d)**k+1) if set(prime_divisors(n)).issubset(set(primes(N+1))) and Omega(n)==k]


def rhs0(N,t):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return (t-d)*binomial(d-t-1,d)/(d+1)+(t-d-1)*(binomial(d-t,d)+d+1)/(d+1)

def rhsK(N,k):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return ((-1)**k*(binomial(d+k,d)-binomial(d+k-1,d)))

#https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/hypergeometric.html

def bino(x,y):
    return gamma(x+1)/(gamma(y+1)*gamma(x-y+1))


def rhsH(N,t):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return ((-1)**t*bino(d+t+1,d)*hypergeometric([1,d+t+2],[t+2],-1)+2**(-d-1))-2**(-d-1)*(2**(d+1)*(-1)**t*bino(d+t,d)*hypergeometric([1,d+t+1],[t+1],-1))


def lhs(N,t):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return sum((-1)**k*(bino(d+k,d)-bino(d+k-1,d)) for k in range(int(t)+1)) 
    #return sum((-1)**Omega(n) for n in range(1,nth_prime(d)**t+1) if set(prime_divisors(n)).issubset(set(primes(N+1))))

def rhs(N,t):
    d = prime_pi(N)
    return sum(rhsK(N,k) for k in range(t+1))

    
for N in range(4,240):
    for t in range(1,14):
        print(N,t,rhsH(N,t).n(),lhs(N,t).n())
```

**Edit**:
Let $B_{N,t} = \{n : \Omega(n) \le t , \hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!), 1 \le n \le p_{\pi(N)}^t\}$, so that

$$\operatorname{binomial}(d+t,d) = L(Q_N,t) = |B_{N,t}|$$

The arguments above show that:

$$\sum_{n \in B_{N,t}} \lambda(n) = F(N,t) = $$

$$=((-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(d+t+1,d) F_{2,1}(1,d+t+2;t+2;-1)+2^{-d-1})-2^{-d-1}(2^{d+1}(-1)^t \operatorname{binomial}(d+t,d)F_{2,1}(1,d+t+1;t+1;-1))$$

hence dividing by the number of points under which the sum runs, we get:

$$\frac{1}{|B_{N,t}|} \sum_{n \in B_{N,t}} \lambda(n) = \frac{1}{|B_{N,t}|} F(N,t) = $$
$$=(-1)^t \frac{d}{t+1}F_{2,1}(1,d+t+2;t+2;-1)+(-1)^t F_{2,1}(1,d+t+2;t+2;-1)+\frac{1}{2^{d+1} \operatorname{binomial}(d+t,d)}+(-1)^{t+1}F_{2,1}(1,d+t+1;t+1;-1)$$

where $d:=\pi(N)$.

Notice the similarity to the prime number theorem:

We have in both cases sets $C_N$ such that:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{|C_N|} \sum_{n \in C_N} \lambda(n) = 0$$

The case $C_N := \{1,\cdots,N\}$ corresponds by Landau equivalently to the prime number theorem.

We observe that:

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} B_{N,t} = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | \Omega(n) \le t \} =: B_{\infty,t}$$

and that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}(\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} B_{N,t} ) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_{\infty,t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \{n \in \mathbb{N} | \Omega(n) \le t \} = \mathbb{N}$$

Similarily:
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}(\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} B_{N,t} ) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} B_{N,\infty} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \{n \in \mathbb{N} | \hat{\pi}(n) \subset \hat{\pi}(N!)\} = \mathbb{N}$$

Hence we have:

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty, N \rightarrow \infty} B_{N,t} = \mathbb{N}$$

(Here we have used that there are infinitely many primes.)

Now let us put $C_N := B_{N,\pi(N)}$.

Then one empirical observation, which I was not able to prove directly, is:

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{|C_N|} \sum_{n \in C_N} \lambda(n) =^? 0$$

which reminds a little bit on the prime number theorem where $C_N:=\{1,\cdots,N\}$.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote, without a comment.